# Some local html pages load slowly on chrome and edge

Tags: google-chrome, browser, microsoft-edge

I have one html page that html page is loading slowly on chrome and edge but only on some machines,
but it loading fast on other machines and on other browser like IE and firefox as well.

So what could be the reason that html page loads slowly on some browsers but on some machines not all
machines.

There are no extension installed on browser.

Reinstalled chrome and tried again, for first time web page loaded as expected but after sometime it started taking time to load.

Comment: Are there any extensions installed in those Chrome and Edge browsers? I suggest that you can disable all the extensions in the browsers and test again. Besides, what are the browsers' versions which load pages slowly? Please update all the versions to the latest and test again.

Comment: No extensions installed. Observed one thing the idle time is about 30sec while loading the page.

Comment: There might be many reasons for the slowly loading. Does the slow performance happen with other pages or only with one specific page? If it also happens with other pages, there might be virus, malware in the machine which influences the performance of the browser.  Besides, I suggest that you can open [F12 dev tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/speed/get-started) in Chrome and Edge to debug the slow performance of the page.

Comment: It's happening for specific page only

Comment: Please use F12 dev tools like what I said in the previous comment to debug the slow performance. It's hard for us to locate the issue with only the text description.

Comment: I use Firefox if I'm working with pure HTML pages that are stored in local computer otherwise I prefer Chrome to work with JavaScript and TypeScript files.